# How to read data from webbrowser using url

Tags: c#

```
  webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
            webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.tayyar.org/");
```

I have this code, which works and I want to put the data in a string to crawl it later on.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

`webBrowser1.DocumentText`

This is what you are looking for probably.

Comment: You can also try to use WebClient.DownloadString
It's a IDisposable object so you can do using (WebClient wc = new WebClient()) { string html = wc.DownloadString(url); }

Comment: You would need to wait for the document to load btw